# How to display custom post type only on a certain page?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have created a custom post type called 'project'. But how do I get the custom post types to display only on my main template? It's a one page website and I don't want it to direct the visitor to a second page.

Wordpress v. 3.5.1

```
 <?php

function my_custom_post_project() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Projects', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Project', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'project' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Project' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Projects' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Project' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Projects' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Projects'
);

$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds my projects and project specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title','editor', 'excerpt'),
    'has_archive'   => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'/','with_front'=>false),
);
register_post_type( 'project', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_project' );

function my_taxonomies_project() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Project Categories', 'taxonomy general name'    ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Project Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Project Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Project Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Project Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Project Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Project Category' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Project Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Project Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Project Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Project Categories' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'project', $args );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_project', 0 );
```

I now changed the code in index.php:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>


    <div id="posts" class="row isotope ">
     <!-- Start Project -->
    <?php   

   $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'project'
   );
   $projects = new WP_Query($args);
   if ($projects->have_posts()) {
   while ($projects->have_posts()) {
   $projects->the_post();
   the_title(); 
   get_the_content();
     }
   }

    ?>
   </div>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The title is brought in but for some reason with a height of 0px. Is this related to the code or is it a completely different matter? Also the content from the editors metabox is not showing.

Comment: You probably need to write a custom loop for displaying them.  We'd need to see the home page template code for your theme in order to make specific recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to answer given the information provided but you probably want ...

```
'has_archive'   => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'/','with_front'=>false),
```

... as part of your arguments when you register the post type and then you can add the post type to the main query for that home/front page...

```
function add_cpt_to_home($qry) {
  if (is_front_page() || is_home()) {
    $post_type = (array)$qry->get('post_type');
    $post_type[] = 'post';
    $post_type[] = 'project';
    $post_type = array_unique(array_filter($post_type));
    $qry->set('post_type',$post_type);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','add_cpt_to_home');
```

Or write a secondary query to pull that post_type.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'project'
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
if ($projects->have_posts()) {
  while ($projects->have_posts()) {
    $projects->the_post();
    the_title(); // etc
  }
}
```

Not tested very well, but as I said it is hard to answer given the information provided.

Comment: I added the extra arguments to project.php and post type code to index.php but the post is not showing up. [https://github.com/martin-metsalu/public](https://github.com/martin-metsalu/public)

Comment: Please post only the relevant code-- [edit] your question. No offense, but I don't have time to read through your whole project on github.

Comment: Sorry about that. I now included only the relevant code on Github.

Comment: My guess would be that the conditions are wrong. That is, the `is_home` and `is_front_page` parts are not correct. I was guessing. Try without any conditions at all and see if it works, but don't leave it that way. Also, you don't need that filter at all if you are creating a new `WP_Query` object.

Comment: Okay the content wasn't showing because it was inside a div which height was 0px. Called the content in using `add the_content()`. Everything is working fine now. Many thanks [s_ha_dum](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) !